# how to find out max number of characters that a tring can take in php?

Tags: size, byte

in php m using code for reading a csv file and storing it into a string separated by comma...
now my string is something like this:

$string= '9878546512','9785456213','9632587412','9753159821','9467521234','9638527412'..and so on
 in future i may have many numbers like this in $string may be 1000 phone numbers copied from csv file to $string...

now my question is that what is maximum size of a string variable in php so that i can limit number of characters read into $string variable...

Answer (score 0):

There's no architectural limit on a single string variable per se. You can slurp in the contents of an entire file, for instance using file_get_contents()

However, a PHP script has a limit on the total memory it can allocate for all variables in a given script execution, so this effectively places a limit on the length of a single string variable too.

This limit is the memory_limit directive in the php.ini configuration file. The memory limit defaults to 128MB in PHP 5.2, and 8MB in earlier releases.